# Text is invisible in ContextMenu

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, contextmenu

Subj. While clicking on ContextMenuItem, event shows that everything is fine, but foreground and background are always totally white.

```
    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu >
        <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="Menu1">

            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item1" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item2" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="item3" Click="MenuItem_Click" />

            <toolkit:ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle >
                <Style TargetType="toolkit:MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="YellowGreen" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </Style>
            </toolkit:ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>

        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: missing x:Key= in Style declaration?

Comment: @RST Not sure: it says "The "Key" attribute can only be used on an element that is contained in "IDictionary"

Comment: Not sure if you are following this example, but if you are you are mixing a few things. The version with list and the version with buttons. http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-contextmenu-in-depth--part1-key-concepts-and-api. I would copy the given example, see if it works, then adjust it to your needs, one thing at a time.

Comment: @RST Yep, i'm folowing "Populating ContextMenu with Items", but i wasn't able to see anything, so i tried to add container style. If to remove styles, it would be exactly as the sample.

Comment: @RST Tried codebehind version like [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/wp7-contextmenu-answers-to-popular-questions) in Question 4. Same crap.

Comment: I am running out of options. If it doesn't work when you copy and paste the given example, then something else is wrong. Maybe you can share some more code.

Comment: @RST Yeah, also samples are working perfect as separate app. i'm checking the styles... i guess, the problem is with color of text: probably, it is showing just with white font.